# Correlated Subquery and Arithmetic in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

This is my second time posting, I got a lot of good feedback from the first post regarding some difficulties. I am working on improving my SQL skills and building this query but I do not understand how to approach

*** i managed to correct all original errors in my question but have one last doubt ***

```
select wo.si_number,ivh.total_cost, wo.bill_name,pnm.pn, pnm.description, woqh.approved_date,ivh.total_price,
(select sum(ivh.total_price - ivh.total_cost) / nullif(ivh.total_price,0) from invc_header ivh where wqh_auto_key = wqh.wqh_auto_key group by ivh.total_price) as CTP,
ivh.post_date, wwt.description, wqh.WQH_AUTO_KEY, wqh.POST_DESC
from wo_operation wo, parts_master pnm,wo_quote_header wqh, 
wo_quote_detail wqd, invc_header ivh, wo_work_type wwt, wo_quote_header woqh
where wo.pnm_auto_key = pnm.pnm_auto_key
and wo.woo_auto_key = wqd.woo_ref
and wqd.wqh_auto_key = wqh.wqh_auto_key
and wqh.WQH_NUMBER = woqh.WQH_NUMBER
and ivh.wqh_auto_key (+)= wqh.wqh_auto_key
and wwt.wwt_auto_key (+)= wo.wwt_auto_key
and wo_type = 'External'
and wqh.POST_DESC is not NULL
and woqh.approved_date between to_date('01/01/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('01/31/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
order by ctp
```

I m not sure how to have the script only pull the rows whose ctp is < 30; how would I incorporate that?

Comment: @CoderLee Hey Lee! I tried adding it in a few different places but I am getting the "invalid identifier" error. Since it stems from the subquery im not sure where to place it

Comment: What kind of value does that sub query return when it works, and are you using PL/SQL T-SQL or something else?

Comment: @CoderLee The value returned is a decimal, so i guess it would <=.30. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer, not sure if that helps!

Comment: I'm not sure why Oracle would throw an Identifier error over a comparison operation, but maybe try AND CPT <= 30.0 so that way it's a decimal. Also Oracle uses PL/SQL, SQL Serverl uses T-SQL, and both are built on top of ANSI SQL which is that standard.

Comment: @CoderLee I believe it has to do with the CTP being a field generated based off the subquery. I dont think I can refer to the alias in the outer query.

Comment: I would disagree, how then would your ORDER BY work? Since it's using the alias as well. That should also throw an Identifier Error if the alias is inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your CTP column is a number you could add that to your `WHERE` like show below where I added it to the end of your query's `WHERE` clause.

```sql
SELECT wo.si_number, 
       ivh.total_cost, 
       wo.bill_name, 
       pnm.pn, 
       pnm.description, 
       woqh.approved_date, 
       ivh.total_price, 
(
    SELECT SUM(ivh.total_price - ivh.total_cost) / NULLIF(ivh.total_price, 0)
    FROM invc_header ivh
    WHERE wqh_auto_key = wqh.wqh_auto_key
    GROUP BY ivh.total_price
) AS CTP, 
       ivh.post_date, 
       wwt.description, 
       wqh.WQH_AUTO_KEY, 
       wqh.POST_DESC
FROM wo_operation wo, 
     parts_master pnm, 
     wo_quote_header wqh, 
     wo_quote_detail wqd, 
     invc_header ivh, 
     wo_work_type wwt, 
     wo_quote_header woqh
WHERE wo.pnm_auto_key = pnm.pnm_auto_key
      AND wo.woo_auto_key = wqd.woo_ref
      AND wqd.wqh_auto_key = wqh.wqh_auto_key
      AND wqh.WQH_NUMBER = woqh.WQH_NUMBER
      AND ivh.wqh_auto_key (+)= wqh.wqh_auto_key
      AND wwt.wwt_auto_key (+)= wo.wwt_auto_key
      AND wo_type = 'External'
      AND wqh.POST_DESC IS NOT NULL
      AND woqh.approved_date BETWEEN to_date('01/01/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND to_date('01/31/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
      AND CTP <= 30
ORDER BY ctp;
```

A simple less than or equal to operation will filter your results to the desired range, so you get only those less than 30 as requested. Also if you need 29 and down you can omit the `=`